# Nmap grepping results

Tags: tcp, awk, grep, nmap, port-scanning

```
$ ./nmap-banners -sV -vvvvv localhost |grep Banners
```

The outputs is:

```
Banner on 127.0.0.1:22/tcp matches ssh: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1.

Banner on 127.0.0.1:25/tcp matches smtp: 220 localhost ESMTP Exim 4.62 Wed, 14 Nov 2007 21:06:10
```

The question is how can I print only the IP Addresses with `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1` using grep or awk

Comment: `./nmap-banners -sV -vvvvv localhost | awk -F: 'NF==3 && /Banner/{gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$1);print $1,$NF}'`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but from your command i cannot see where you actually put the words ( in this case "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1" ) so that awk can seach for

Comment: He didn't. Replace the `/Banner/` bit with `/SSH..../` instead and that should do what you want. Though I would probably use `awk '$6 == "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2" {print $3}` assuming getting the full `127.0.0.1:22/tcp` as output is ok. If not then `{split($3, a, /:/); print a[1]}` should do that.

Comment: okay . i got it . so now how do i get the results of the scan with the specific banner (ip addresses only) to a text file using grep or awk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for lines that contain both strings `Banner` and `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1` then you can also use grep and cut.

Grep version with cut

```
nmap-banners -sV -vvvvv localhost|
grep 'Banner.*SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1'|
cut -d" " -f3|
cut -d":" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
Banner on 127.0.0.1:22/tcp matches ssh: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5ubuntu1.

Banner on 127.0.0.1:25/tcp matches smtp: 220 localhost ESMTP Exim 4.62 Wed, 14 Nov 2007 21:06:10

$ awk -F'[ :]' '/SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2/{print $3}' file
127.0.0.1
```